The diagonal operators and unconditionality
The following is well-known:
Theorem: Let $X$ be a Banach space with an unconditional basis $(e_n)_n$.
Then the space of the diagonal operators with respect the basis $(e_n)_n$ endowed with
the operator norm is isomorphic to $l_{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$.
The proof of the theorem is an easy consequence of the unconditionality of $(e_n)_n$. In fact the following holds:
For every unconditional basis $(e_n)_n$ there exists $ M \ge 1$ such that for every $(a_n)_n$, $(b_n)_n$ real sequences, we have,
$$\Big\|\sum_{n}b_na_ne_n \Big\| \leq M \sup_n |b_n| \Big\|\sum_na_ne_n\Big\|$$
and this yields the result.
This naturally leads to the following question:
Question 1: Let $X$ be a Banach space with a Schauder basis $(e_n)_n$ such that the space of the diagonal operators is isomorphic to $l_{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$. Is the basis then unconditional?
The following could be easier to answer:
Question 2: Under the assumptions of Question 1 does there exist an unconditional subsequence of $(e_n)_n$?

It is shown that if the space of compact diagonal operators contain a copy of $c_0$, then Q2 has positive answer. See Spaces of diagonal operators
H.M. Wark, Thm 30,  https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/PL00004874.pdf. Also related A. Sersouri. (1988). Diagonal operators in basis spaces. Mathematische Zeitschrift, 199(4), 491–499. doi:10.1007/bf01161638 https://www.tesble.com/10.1007/bf01161638
